# Building and packaging a portable ffmpeg Linux program ('GLIBC_2.27' not found)

Tags: linux, gcc, ffmpeg, glibc, static-linking

I am trying to build a portable version of ffmpeg to run on major Linux distributions, with the final user only having to extract the distributed targz package to the appropriate directory.

My previous builds on Ubuntu 16.04 worked fine. I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and new builds, when run on Fedora 27 with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./ffmpeg`, show errors:

```
./ffmpeg: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by ./libavfilter.so.7)
./ffmpeg: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by ./libavformat.so.58)
```

Which i interpret as *the `libavxxx` libraries want to dynamically link against system libraries `libc` and `libm` that would have been compiled with `GLIBC_2.27`, but those libs have been compiled with an older GLIBC version*.

Note that the fact the errors show from `libavxxx.so` is not the point, as if i compile `ffmpeg` as a fat binary (`libavxxx` linked statically), i get the same error from `ffmpeg`.

The only workaround i have found so far is to copy the build system `libc.so.6` and `libm.so.6` libraries to the directory containing the binaries and make them part of the `ffmpeg` package.

Is there a better way to handle this issue ?

Comment: Portable : Build on "older" ... to be used with "newer". I.e. an Ubuntu 18.04 build with glibc (libc6) version 2.27 cannot be used in Fedora 27 : glibc-2.26 . **Note** : glibc *is* your OS ( together with the kernel), and cannot be changed.

Comment: You can take a look into my PR to bitcoin, https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/13177/files . use ld `--wrap` option to replace the function and use `.symver` asm point to the older function.

Comment: Ken: your solution looks smart. Maybe too smart and i don't really understand all the implications and risks. I went for Knud suggestion, setup an Ubuntu 16.04 VM to recompile the whole thing. So far, so good. Thanks.